# detect change in network on phone gap

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have a situation wherein if a user logs in from one network-->goes to home screen-->switches network.if he switches network i have to run  a particular scenario and below is the blueprint that i came up with.

if the user logs in from one network i am storing the ip address as a1.b1.c1.d1. and
if the user switches to another network i am storing the ip address as a2.b2.c2.d2

can i compare a1 with a2 to tell that i have switched networks.Is this the right way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've developped a plugin that probably will help you on this (not sure if an event is raised in all cases when the network interface has been changed, for sure that it is when internet reachability changes):

https://github.com/appfeel/connectivity-monitor-cordova

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  var myHostToObserve = "www.appfeel.com";

  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  document.addEventListener(connectivity.events.onReachabilityChanged, onReachabilityChanged, false)
  connectivity.observeRemoteHostName(myHostToObserve);
}

function onReachabilityChanged(e) {
  console.log(e.interface);
  swich(e.interface) {
    case connectivity.DISCONNECTED:
      console.log('DISCONNECTED');
      break;
    case WIFI:
      console.log('WIFI');
      break;
    case WIMAX:
      console.log('WIMAX');
      break;
    case ETHERNET:
      console.log('ETHERNET');
      break;
    case MOBILE:
      console.log('MOBILE');
      break;
    case UNDEFINED:
      console.log('UNDEFINED');
      break;
  }

  if (e.connected) {
    console.log("Is connected");
  } else {
    console.log("Is not connected");
  }

  swich(e.observer) {
    case HOST:
      console.log('HOST');
      break;
    case INTERNET:
      console.log('INTERNET');
      break;
    case LOCALWIFI:
      console.log('LOCALWIFI');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Miquel,thnx for the reply.gng by your code,it only tels me which network i'm on eg:wifi/mobile.Does it tell me that i have switched networks?

Comment: This is what I'm not really sure of, you could try as it was not the real intention of this plugin. Please let me know if it does, as I will update the documentation :)